Prove that for all $x,y>0$ with $x^3+y^4 \leq x^2+y^3$ we have $x^3+y^3 \leq 2$

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y>0$ and $x^3+y^4 \leq x^2+y^3$. We want to show that $x^3+y^3 \leq 2$.

Our analysis prof proposed this to us as extra homework and hasn't told us the answer since
I've tried using Hölder's inequality, but I can't seem to make much from it.
Can anyone help?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I reworded what wimatew said @AnneBauval, wimatew said "I've tried with Hölder's inequality but i can't seem to get anywhere."

Did you try looking for maximum of $f(x,y) = x^3+y^3$ on the compact set ${(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\geq 0,, y\geq 0,, x^3+y^4\leq x^2+y^3}$ using standard calculus tools like inspecting critical points of $f$ in the interior and using Lagrange multipliers for the boundary of the domain?

If one notices that when $x = y = 1$, two expressions hold with equality, then one can prove it easily. I have three solutions without calculus.  I think there are more solutions.

You need to edit the question giving more detail of your attempt, or source, context, motivation etc.
